# Angularjs: How to add active class on buttons

Tags: html, angularjs

Can I add an `active` class on buttons with AngularJS?

For example:

```
<button class="first">first</button>
<button class="second">second</button>
<button class="third active">third</button>
<button class="fourth">fourth</button>
```

By default I want to set active class on `third` and then remove the class and add it to the selected button.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<button class="first" ng-class="{'active':selcted == 'first'}">first</button>
<button class="second" ng-class="{'active':selcted == 'second'}">second</button>
<button class="third" ng-class="{'active':selcted == 'third'}">third</button>
<button class="fourth" ng-class="{'active':selcted == 'fourth'}">fourth</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.selcted = 'third';
```

Comment: It only adds the active class to the `third` button and doesn't remove it when I select another button